# jQuery, Bootstrap modals and Aria items

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/8g4ezaeg/) that shows a puzzle.  I am using jQuery to set `data-` and `aria` properties in other apps but all of a sudden I can't seem to make it work in this app.

The fiddle is minimal.  Nothing will be displayed in the result pane.  You can use your favorite developer tools to drill down to the DOM object that represents the modal.  In Chrome and FireFox I do not see the `data` or `aria` attributes that the javascript suggests should be there.

The outer div for the modal is currently being created as:

```
var modal = $("<div/>").prop("id", "popupError")
  .addClass("modal")
  .addClass("fade")
  .prop("tabindex", "-1")
  .prop("role", "dialog")
  .prop("aria-labelledby", "Pop up error")
  .prop("aria-hidden", "true")
  .appendTo("body");
```

I had the thought that the DOM element might have to already exist so I tried:

```
var modal = $("<div/>").prop("id", "popupError")
  .addClass("modal")
  .addClass("fade")
  .prop("tabindex", "-1")
  .appendTo("body");

$("#popupError")
    .prop("role", "dialog")
    .prop("aria-labelledby", "Pop up error")
    .prop("aria-hidden", "true");
```

with the same results.  I have also tried using `attr` instead of `prop`.

ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works with `attr`.

```
var modal = $("<div/>").prop("id", "popupError")
    .addClass("modal")
    .addClass("fade")
    .prop("tabindex", "-1")
    .attr("role", "dialog")
    .attr("aria-labelledby", "Pop up error")
    .attr("aria-hidden", "true")
    .appendTo("body");
```

Comment: dang it.  it was not working with `attr` just before I posted this question.

thank you